# Solving Implicit Solution

Tags: python, implicit, differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve this question using Python. It is an implicit equation with a differential which is equal to the original equation. How do I go about this?

The equation is

```
F(x,t) = a*x^n + b*(t^o)*(x^m) + c, with a=5,b=-3,c=2,n=1.5,m=5.5,o=3
```

Comment: Can you please add what options is being tried out.

Comment: Where exactly is the differential part? `x'(t)=F(x(t),t)`? What exactly is the problem with solving that ODE, the numerical solvers should have no problem with integrating it in positive time direction.

Comment: So, X(t=0) = 1. I am expected to solve this implicitly and explicitly but unsure of which python package to use. Also, if you differentiate x'(t+dt) = x(t) + dt*F(x(t+dt),t+dt).

Comment: I have been trying to use ODEINT but not sure how to define the model for multiple timesteps. I have to keep solving the same equation for dt = 0.001,0.01,0.025 & 0.05